# Looking for a car model with huge tank size and acceptable mileage

Tags: fuel-tank

I'm planning a road trip. I will probably spend a lot of time outside of civilization. For convenience I will take a generator with me so I can power my computer, cooking devices etc. In my country the amount of fuel I'm allowed to transport in cans is limited. I've read about similar limitations in other countries so I thought about using the tank as a fuel reservoir. I'm looking for a car which has acceptable mileage and a large fuel tank. It doesn't matter  if it's gasoline / diesel. Can anyone knowledgeable make a recommendation. I'm not looking for a mobile home but rather a normal car, maybe a cheap SUV.

I'm located in Switzerland. (Central Europe)

Comment: Landrovers - older ones lwb, had the possibility of 3 fuel tanks as a standard option from the factory… But finding one of those… Rarer than hen’s teeth.

Comment: Auxiliary fuel tanks are not uncommon for overlanding rigs (particularly Australia). A good dual-battery setup (with solar perhaps) will run your computer, then cook on propane.

Comment: It also depends on your budget.